# string formatted as base64 to base64 object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

From a post request, I receive a base64 in JSON. Problem is that I can't just change the file type from string to base64 since it's already formatted as base64. need the base64 to convert it back to an image.

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
img = json_data['img']
print(img)
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
   fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to decode it, add the third line which decodes the string to base64

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
img = json_data['img']
imgdata = base64.b64decode(img)
filename = 'upload/newimg.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? If so, could you explain how it answers the question?